# Will Asarum europaeum add a ginger flavor?

Tags: ginger

I was looking through a cooking catalog, and came across GINGER, EUROPEAN which made me wonder if this is like normal ginger that you cook with.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asarum_europaeum implies it can be used as a spice but one of its references says it has been used in herbal medicine to induce vomiting. It's perfectly possible that both are true and the quantity makes the difference, but it suggests that some caution is needed.

Comment: Chris, if it's like American Wild Ginger, it's a matter of whether you eat the root pulp or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: kinda-sorta, in a weak way.

Long answer: European wild ginger is [grown as a ground cover](https://home.howstuffworks.com/european-wild-ginger.htm), not for culinary purposes.  It is closely related to American Wild Ginger, though, which can be used to cook with, but it has a [weaker flavor than Chinese ginger, less pulp, and you shouldn't actually eat the roots](https://foragerchef.com/how-to-find-and-use-wild-ginger/).  I would presume European ginger to be a very similar experience, but only have experience with the American variety.